# Is executing directly through a TTY more secure than through a terminal emulator?

Tags: x11, security, tty, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator

Question assumes X11 is installed on the machine, regardless of which is used.

Answer (score 2):

With X, it's possible to sniff the X events.  Running in a *console*, there isn't *that* aspect.  But other users on the system with enough privilege could in principle trace your process to show the system calls (including reads/writes).  So the degree to which one or the other is insecure depends on who is accessing the machine.

Comment: Thomas, +1, but _tty_ would be more technically appropriate than _console_, no?

Comment: That's debatable: almost everyone here saying "tty" is referring to [*Linux console*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Linux_consoles), which is **not** a teletype.  You can discuss terminology at length.  I've used teletypes.